# How do I set an array with another Array?

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, nsarray

```
@property (nonatomic, retain)   NSMutableArray *filteredListContent;
----
@synthesize filteredListContent;


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {     


    NSMutableArray *test = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [test addObject:@"test string"];
    [filteredListContent addObjectsFromArray:test];


    NSLog(@"%@", test);
    NSLog(@"Filtered Array is %@", filteredListContent);

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

---

My Log for test shows 'test string' but 'Filtered list array is (null)'

How do I set the array 'filteredListContent' with the array test...

What am I doing wrong? :-(

Answer (score 2):

Are you creating and initializing filtersListContent anywhere?  Your code looks right, that should work.

You should also make sure to release your `test` variable, you have a memory leak here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually create filteredListContent, say with [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]. The error you are getting is that you are calling a method, -addObjectsFromArray:, on an object that is still nil: never created. As such, it just returns nil, and the list is never filtered.

Answer (score 0):

filteredListContent is a pointer to a NSMutableArray, it does not have any memory assigned to it, as a result you cannot call methods on it. The compiler does not generate an error because you are passing a message to `nil` which is perfectly alright.

Answer (score -1):

Thanx for that.

so I changed the line...

```
[filteredListContent addObjectsFromArray:test];
```

to read...

```
filteredListContent = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:test];
```

This done it.  I think I understand it now, though I declared it, I never created it...

Thanx.

Comment: What out for memory management problem. Check out http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html.

Comment: `$prevComment =~ s/^What/Watch/;`